# Remote Hybrid Android install Documentation

Tags: hybrid-remote

I have followed these instructions for forcedroid

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK
or 
https://developer.salesforce.com/mobile/getting-started/android#hybrid

When I do force create it builds the project fine but when I follow the directions after i.e.
To use your new application in Eclipse, do the following:
   - Go to File -> Import... 
   - Choose Andriod-> Existing Android code into Workspace, and click Next >
   - For the root directory, browse to the MyAPP folder
   - pick the following projects //SmartSnync SmartStore SalesforceSDK platforms android Covdovalib note these are not the file paths but you get the idea 
   - Click Finish
   - Run your application by right-clicking the project in Project Explorer, and choosing Run As ->

So If I follow these directions and import the follow into my workspace I get close to 400 errors.
Is there a step missing in the documentation somewhere?